# Rails & RSpec: Testing CRUD actions with shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Testing RESTful actions of multiple Rails controllers with RSpec can generate a lot of code repetition. The following code is my first attempt at using shared examples to DRY things up.

Here is what I don't like about the code, could not find a better way and would like your help to improve:

- The shared examples require that specific variables are set within `let` blocks within the controller spec (high coupling). I have tried to use the model name to infer the factory name and create the test data within the share examples. It works well to create the record and records variables. However, some models require the presence of associations and FactoryGirl.attributes_for does not create associated records, so validation fails. So, valid_attributes are created differently for different models. The only (likely bad) way I could think of creating valid_attributes within shared examples is to pass a string containing the code used to create the attributes and evaluate it (eval) within the shared examples
- The tests that assert redirection use `eval` to call Rails' route/path helpers. Different controllers in this app have different redirect behaviors. After creating or updating a record, some controllers redirect to the #show action, others to #index. The problem is that when expecting a redirect to #show, AFAIK, we have to know the record ID in order to build the expected URL. And we don't know the record ID within the controller spec. We only know it within the shared examples. So how can we pass an expected redirect URL from the controller spec to the shared example if we do not yet know what that URL is (because we don't know the record ID)?

Also, please let me know if you spot any additional issues.

The controller spec:

```
# spec/controllers/quotes_controller_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe QuotesController, :focus, :type => :controller do
  login_admin

  let(:model) { Quote }
  let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote) }
  let(:records) { FactoryGirl.create_pair(:quote) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:quote, quote: "New quote") }
  let(:invalid_attributes) { valid_attributes.update(quote: nil) }

  include_examples "GET #index"
  include_examples "GET #show"
  include_examples "GET #new"
  include_examples "GET #edit"
  include_examples "POST #create", "quote_path(assigns(:quote))"
  include_examples "PATCH #update", "quote_url"
  include_examples "DELETE #destroy", "quotes_url"
end
```

The shared examples:

```
# spec/support/shared_examples/controller_restful_actions.rb
def ivar_name(model, plural: false)
  if plural
    model.name.pluralize.underscore.to_sym
  else
    model.name.underscore.to_sym
  end
end

def record_name(model)
  model.name.underscore.to_sym
end

RSpec.shared_examples "GET #index" do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :index
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :index
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "populates instance variable with an array of records" do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(ivar_name(model, plural: true))).to match_array(records)
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "GET #show" do
  describe "GET #show" do

    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :show, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :show, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns the requested record to an instance variable" do
      get :show, id: record
      expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to eq(record)
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "GET #new" do
  describe "GET #new" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :new
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :new
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns a new record to an instance variable" do
      get :new
      expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to be_a_new(model)
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "GET #edit" do
  describe "GET #edit" do
    let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(factory_name(model)) }

    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns the requested record to an instance variable" do
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to eq(record)
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "POST #create" do |redirect_path_helper|
  describe "POST #create" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      post :create, { record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      post :create, { record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves the new record in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, { record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        }.to change(model, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved record to an instance variable" do
        post :create, { record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to be_a(model)
        expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to #{redirect_path_helper}" do
        post :create, { record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(redirect_path_helper))
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not save the new record in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, { record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        }.not_to change(model, :count)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved record an instance variable" do
        post :create, { record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to be_a_new(model)
      end

      it "re-renders the :new template" do
        post :create, { record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "PATCH #update" do |redirect_path_helper|
  describe "PATCH #update" do
    let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(factory_name(model)) }

    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "updates the requested record" do
        patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        record.reload
        expect(record).to have_attributes(valid_attributes)
      end

      it "assigns the requested record to an instance variable" do
        put :update,  { :id => record, record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to eq(record)
      end

      it "redirects to #{redirect_path_helper}" do
        patch :update,  { :id => record, record_name(model) => valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(redirect_path_helper))
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not update the requested record" do
        expect {
          patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        }.not_to change { record.reload.attributes }
      end

      it "assigns the record to an instance variable" do
        patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(ivar_name(model))).to eq(record)
      end

      it "re-renders the :edit template" do
        patch :update, { :id => record, record_name(model) => invalid_attributes }
        expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
      end
    end
  end
end


RSpec.shared_examples "DELETE #destroy" do |redirect_path_helper|
  describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "deletes the record" do
      # Records are lazily created. Here we must force its creation.
      record
      expect{
        delete :destroy, id: record
      }.to change(model, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to #{redirect_path_helper}" do
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(redirect_path_helper))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not an answer but too long for a comment:

First of all you can wrap all of those in a `shared_examples_for` block e.g.

```
shared_examples_for 'a CRUD Controller' do 
  context "GET #index" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :index
      expect(response).to require_login
    end
   ####
  end
  context "GET #show" do
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get :show, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login
    end
   ####
  end
end
```

Secondly You can have shared examples inside shared examples to the above can be

```
shared_examples_for 'a CRUD Controller' do 
  shared_examples_for 'authenticatable' do |view:,params:{}|
    it "requires login" do
      sign_out current_user
      get view, **params
      expect(response).to require_login
    end
  end

  context "GET #index" do
   it_behaves_like 'authenticatable', view: :index 
   ####
  end
  context "GET #show" do
   it_behaves_like 'authenticatable', view: :show, id: record
   ####
  end
end
```

Third you can assign variables inside a `it_behaves_like` block eg.

```
RSpec.describe QuotesController, :focus, :type => :controller do
  login_admin
  it_behaves_like 'a CRUD Controller' do  
    let(:model) { Quote }
    let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote) }
    let(:records) { FactoryGirl.create_pair(:quote) }
    let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:quote, quote: "New quote") }
    let(:invalid_attributes) { valid_attributes.update(quote: nil) }
  end
end
```

Fourth this too can be simplified

```
shared_examples_for 'a CRUD Controller' do |model:| 
  singular,plural = 2.times.map { |n| model.name.pluralize(n).underscore.to_sym }
  let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(singular)
  let(:records) {FactoryGirl.create_pair(singular) }
  let(:valid_attributes) do 
    # build should create the nested associations correctly as long 
    # as your factories are right
    FactoryGirl.build(singular).attributes.delete_if do |k,_| 
      # this is because ActiveRecord#attributes contains columns 
      # you don't want to be considered updateable
      ["id","created_at","updated_at"].include?(k)
    end 
  end 
  let(:invalid_attributes) do 
    # create an :invalid trait in your factory so that 
    # you don't have to worry about the model
    FactoryGirl.build(singular, :invalid).attributes.delete_if do |k,_| 
      ["id","created_at","updated_at"].include?(k)
    end 
  end 
  ####
end

RSpec.describe QuotesController, :focus, :type => :controller do
  login_admin
  it_behaves_like 'a CRUD Controller', model: Quote
end
```

Finally you are going to find that using a memoized `let!` will help drastically since you are creating an extraordinary amount of records in those tests as it stands now. This will degrade performance drastically and if you get to a model that has certain globally unique attributes your tests will fail everywhere.

Hopefully this helps start pointing you in the right direction

**Update** to control testing actions

```
shared_examples_for 'a CRUD Controller' do |model:|
  accessible_method = ->(meth) { public_methods.include?(meth) }

  context "GET #index", if: controller.method_defined?(:index) do
    it_behaves_like 'authenticatable', view: :index 
    ####
  end
  context "GET #show", if: controller.method_defined?(:show) do
    it_behaves_like 'authenticatable', view: :show, id: record
    ####
  end 
end
```

Comment: Regarding wrapping all tests in a `shared_examples_for` block, I have chosen to keep them separate because not all controllers implement all CRUD actions. About having shared examples inside shared examples, it would allow more granular control over which tests are executed. However, it would result in a lot more lines of code, wouldn't it? About setting variables within a `it_behaves_like` block, I'm probably missing your point. Please don't get me wrong, I appreciate your suggestions, I'm just trying to understand the benefits of applying them to my code.

Comment: Regardind the `this too can be simplified` part, those are some great suggestions, thanks! I'll definitely create an `:invalid` trait and experiment with memoized `let!`. About using `build` to create valid attributes, I've been doing that. However, I find it is unable to create associated records for HMT and HABTM relationships. The only solution I've found so far is using `#merge`: `FactoryGirl.build(:quote, quote: "New quote").attributes.symbolize_keys.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at).merge({ theme_ids: [FactoryGirl.create(:theme).id] })`

Comment: @BrunoFacca in regards to your first point this too can be controlled. ( I will post a snippet in a second). Regarding your second point factories can control how a relationship is "built" using association in the factory itself.

Comment: @BrunoFacca this is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/engineersmnky/75f4147005c5a3f78d7befe2ce0e91a8) of how we have refactored these types of tests in our API. Don't worry about the tests them selves as they are far different from yours but maybe the structuring can help you get an idea.

Comment: @BrunoFacca in addition to allowing us to template testing in this manner. The testing template then made it clear that we could template our API Engines (these are not rails engines). So now when we need a new engine it is a simple rake task that assembles all the structure for us. DRYing out the testing has helped us refactor our actual application and cleaned it up immensely while ensuring standardization across the whole application so that the developers do not need to concern themselves with the underlying implementation specifics

Comment: I haven't thought about checking whether each controller action is implemented and running tests conditionally. That will allow a lot of extra flexibility in my shared examples. Thanks! Regarding creating HMT or HABTM associations within a factory, could you provide an example? I've searched and experimented a lot and was unable to do this. Also, thanks for the Gist, it contains some very interesting code and I'll certainly learn from it.

Comment: @BrunoFacca have you read though this? https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl You can create the associated objects in call back blocks conditionally or unconditionally. As for HMT you should create the direct association e.g. the "Though" part and allow it to create the nested one. That being said if you are not enforcing the need for the existence of these child objects then you should test that functionality outside of a standardized structure (read shared example)

Comment: I did not read that article. Will experiment with callbacks in order to create associations. Thanks. BTW, many models validate the presence of associated objects, so creating them is necessary.

Comment: @BrunoFacca no problem good luck. Takes a bit of trial an error to work out the kinks but in the end it is well worth it

Comment: I have created an answer with the improved code (based on your suggestions). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the improved code (based on engineersmnky's suggestions). Any suggestions for further improvements are welcome.

Controller spec:

```
# spec/controllers/quotes_controller_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe QuotesController, :type => :controller do
  it_behaves_like "a CRUD controller",
                  model: Quote,
                  create_redirect_path_helper: "quote_path(assigns(:quote))",
                  update_redirect_path_helper: "quote_url",
                  delete_redirect_path_helper: "quotes_url"
end
```

Shared examples:

```
# spec/support/shared_examples/controller_restful_actions.rb
RSpec.shared_examples "a CRUD controller" do |model:,
                                              create_redirect_path_helper:,
                                              update_redirect_path_helper:,
                                              delete_redirect_path_helper:| 

  def self.controller_has_action?(action)
    described_class.action_methods.include?(action.to_s)
  end

  resource_singular = model.name.underscore.to_sym
  resource_plural = model.name.pluralize.underscore.to_sym

  before(:each) { login_admin }

  let(:record) { FactoryGirl.create(resource_singular) }
  let(:records) { FactoryGirl.create_pair(resource_singular) }
  # Models that validate the presence of associated records require some
  # hacking in the factory to include associations in the attributes_for output.
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(resource_singular) }
  # All factories must have a trait called :invalid
  let(:invalid_attributes) do
    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(resource_singular, :invalid)
  end

  describe "GET #index", if: controller_has_action?(:index) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      get :index
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :index
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "populates @#{resource_plural} with an array of #{resource_plural}" do
      # Force records to be created before the request.
      records
      get :index
      # Required when testing the User model, or else the user created
      # by the Devise login helper skews the result of this test.
      expected_records = assigns(resource_plural) - [@current_user]
      expect(expected_records).to match_array(records)
    end
  end

  describe "GET #show", if: controller_has_action?(:show) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      get :show, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :show, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns the requested #{resource_singular} to an instance variable" do
      get :show, id: record
      expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to eq(record)
    end
  end

  describe "GET #new", if: controller_has_action?(:new) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      get :new
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :new
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns a new #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
      get :new
      expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to be_a_new(model)
    end
  end

  describe "GET #edit", if: controller_has_action?(:edit) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "assigns #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
      get :edit, id: record
      expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to eq(record)
    end
  end

  describe "POST #create", if: controller_has_action?(:create) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      post :create, { resource_singular => valid_attributes }
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      post :create, { resource_singular => valid_attributes }
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves the new #{resource_singular} in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, { resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        }.to change(model, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns the saved #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
        post :create, { resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to be_an_instance_of(model)
        expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to #{create_redirect_path_helper}" do
        post :create, { resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(create_redirect_path_helper))
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not save the new #{resource_singular} in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, { resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        }.not_to change(model, :count)
      end

      it "assigns the unsaved #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
        post :create, { resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to be_a_new(model)
      end

      it "re-renders the :new template" do
        post :create, { resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        expect(response).to render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "PATCH #update", if: controller_has_action?(:update) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      patch :update, { :id => record,
                       resource_singular => valid_attributes }
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      patch :update, { :id => record,
                       resource_singular => valid_attributes }
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "updates the requested #{resource_singular}" do
        patch :update, { :id => record,
                         resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        record.reload
        # Required when testing Devise's User model with reconfirmable on
        record.try(:confirm)
        expect(record).to have_attributes(valid_attributes)
      end

      it "assigns the #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
        put :update,  { :id => record,
                        resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to eq(record)
      end

      it "redirects to #{update_redirect_path_helper}" do
        patch :update,  { :id => record,
                          resource_singular => valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(update_redirect_path_helper))
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not update the #{resource_singular}" do
        # Do not attempt to "refactor" the following to any of the following:
        # not_to change { quote }
        # not_to change { quote.attributes }
        # not_to have_attributes(invalid_attributes)
        # None of the above will work. See
        # https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/996#issuecomment-310729685
        expect {
          patch :update, { :id => record,
                           resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        }.not_to change { record.reload.attributes }
      end

      it "assigns the #{resource_singular} to @#{resource_singular}" do
        patch :update, { :id => record,
                         resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        expect(assigns(resource_singular)).to eq(record)
      end

      it "re-renders the :edit template" do
        patch :update, { :id => record,
                         resource_singular => invalid_attributes }
        expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE #destroy", if: controller_has_action?(:destroy) do
    it "requires login" do
      logout
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(response).to require_login_web
    end

    it "enforces authorization" do
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(controller).to enforce_authorization
    end

    it "deletes the #{resource_singular}" do
      # Force record to be created before the `expect` block.
      # Otherwise, it is both created and deleted INSIDE the block, causing the
      # count not to change.
      record
      expect{
        delete :destroy, id: record
      }.to change(model, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to #{delete_redirect_path_helper}" do
      delete :destroy, id: record
      expect(response).to redirect_to(eval(delete_redirect_path_helper))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `let` blocks, does it not work if you pass in the model as a parameter to the shared example like you do with the redirect_path_helper?

```
include_examples "GET #index", Quote
```

and then in your shared_example you can use the `record_name` method to create `record` and `records` from FactoryGirl and generate valid_attributes and invalid_attributes (you could create an `:invalid_quote` factory as well for invalid attributes, not sure if that's considered a good practice/idea with FactoryGirl though) from there.

For the second problem, you don't need to use the named route helpers, `url_for(controller: :quote)` and `url_for(@quote)` should both work.

Comment: I have tried to use the model name to infer the factory name and create the test data within the share examples. It works well to create the `record` and `records` variables. However, some models require the presence of associations and `FactoryGirl.attributes_for` does not create associated records, so validation fails. So, `valid_attributes` are created differently for different models. The only (bad) way I could think of creating `valid_attributes`within shared examples is to pass a string containing the code used to create the attributes and evaluate it (`eval`) within the shared examples.

Comment: For the second problem: different controllers have different redirect behaviors. After creating or updating a record, some controllers redirect to the `#show` action, others to `#index`. The problem is that when expecting a redirect to `#show`, AFAIK, we have to know the record ID in order to build the expected URL. And we don't know the record ID within the controller spec. We only know it within the shared examples. So how can we pass an expected redirect URL from the controller spec to the shared example if we do not yet know what that URL is (because we don't know the record ID)?